# Is generically finite equivalent to finite extension when surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective morphism of varieties. Do the following conditions equivalent?

1. $f$ is generically finite
2. $[K(X):K(Y)]<\infty$
3. $dim(X) = dim(Y)$
4. There is  an open set $V\subseteq Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V)\rightarrow V$ is finite

Comment: Aren't $1$ and $2$ equivalent by definition?

Comment: I use the definition on Hartshorne chapter 2 exercise 3.7 which defines generic finite as $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is finite set for generic point $\eta\in Y$.

Comment: This is a special case of a famous technical exercise in Hartshorne. See chapter 2, exercise 3.7.